# Is "on the side" an adverbial phrase you can plug anywhere?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if you can plug "on the side" (adjacent to me) as an adverbial phrase you can plug anywhere.

> She stood next to me when I was watching the TV and stared at me on
>   the side.

Can you think of an example where you can't plug "on the side" after a verb + object group?

Comment: If I had enough time, I could probably think of one million examples, because we just don't use 'on the side' like that. Try to avoid the 'plugging in' mindset. English is not Lego.

Comment: Is there a problem with the particular example sentence? What would you replace it with? What other words or phrases are there?

Comment: [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-the-side) shows some example uses of the phrase "on the side". The American page is quite similar. Your example makes no sense at all even from your own meaning "adjacent to me".

Comment: "On the side" is an idiom here, meaning slyly, or when no one was looking. But it is not mobile: it must be located post-verbally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot just use that phrase anywhere. The construction is syntactically correct, but it has semantic issues.

In your sentence, *on the side* doesn't make sense. What are you trying to describe?

- She was standing beside you and looking at you.
- She was staring at your side.
- She was looking at you sideways.
- Something else.

Typically, *on the side* has a few meanings:

- In addition to. I'd like a sandwich with some fries *on the side*.
- A figurative term for cheating. He was seeing someone else *on the side*.
- A literal term. I was standing *on the side* of the crowd.

But *stared at me on the side* doesn't correspond to any of the normal meanings, so it sounds strange. Whatever it is that is meant would likely not be understood. Somebody hearing that sentence would probably ask, "What do you mean?"

Comment: She was standing beside you and looking at you or she was on the side of him and staring at him while his gaze was perpendicular to hers.

Comment: Then why do we say "I was standing on the side while watching the performers on stage"

Comment: @repomonster It's based on context. *I was standing on the side* means you were *literally* standing to the side of something. (But you can't say *just* that.)  In your latest example, it's on the side of the stage. But nobody ever *stares* at somebody *on the side*. Not unless more context is explicitly given: *I stared at her* ***on the side [of the stage]***.

Comment: Are you saying we need to say "I stared at him, on the side."? With a comma to say that you are standing on the side of him?

Comment: It's sometimes used as an idiom, meaning "slyly glanced" or when no one was looking. Maybe it only occurs in BrE.

Comment: Hmm, do you have a source. It would be sort of synonymous if it were indeed the case.

Comment: @repomonster I don't know what you mean by *I stared at him, on the side*. (Comma or not.) You could say *I stared at him while standing next to him.* Or *I stared at him from his left side*. But *on the side* is not something that's used (at least in US English) that I've heard used as an adverbial form of looking at someone. The idiom for that would be *I gave him side-eye.* And if you mean  physical standing at his side, we would never add *on the side* to mean that.

Comment: But "standing next to him" or "from his left side"  is a mouthful, there has to be a shorter way to say this...

Comment: @repomonster *She stood at my side while I was watching TV, and stared at me.*

Comment: "I see a monster staring at me on the side of the screen!" Isn't this correct? "I know a movie where a monster stares at you on the side of the screen throughout its entirety." I am not sure if I am clinically insane, but these two sounds idiomatic.

Comment: @repomonster Yes, that's fine—since you specified *of the screen* at the end. But this would not be: *I see  a monster staring on the side.*